# Grails 4.0.2. Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-4

I created a new grails app using below code

```
grails create-app myapp --profile=rest-api
```

I modified **ApplicationController** and added *namespace* to it, It is as below:

```
class ApplicationController implements PluginManagerAware {

     /** The Namespace for the version of the API, see http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/REST.html#versioningResources */
     static namespace = "v1"

     GrailsApplication grailsApplication
     GrailsPluginManager pluginManager

     def index() {
         [grailsApplication: grailsApplication, pluginManager: pluginManager]
     } 
}
```

There is a `index.gson` file present under `views/application/` Directory.

I run this setup using `grails run-app` and point my browser to `http://localhost:8080`

It throws following exeption:

```
<=======2020-04-08 16:01:31.616 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'] with root cause
```

However if I modify controller code an use `render`, everything works fine.

```
render(view:'index',model: [grailsApplication: grailsApplication, pluginManager: pluginManager])
```

> Output of grails -v
>   Grails Version: 4.0.2
>   JVM Version: 1.8.0_171
>   OS: macOS High Sierra

Answer (score 0):

See **[Selecting Views For Namespaced Controllers](http://docs.grails.org/4.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews)**

The correct path for the namespaced view should be:

```
grails-app/views/v1/application/index.gson
```

Comment: Thanks @erichelgeson, I read it, last line says `If the view is not found in the namespaced directory then Grails will fallback to looking for the view in the non-namespaced directory.` Also when using method `render`, all works.

"

Comment: oh, you're right! I would open an issue then as I'd expect it to work based on the docs you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you @erichelgeson. For the moment I'll use render to proceed. Thanks again.

Comment: Here is link to repo, that reproduce issue: https://github.com/devravi/grails_view_index_issue